# Hello, tell me what to write in this code and where to close the modal on mouse click outside the modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, jsx

I'm making a modal window and my task is to make it close by clicking the mouse outside this window and pressing Esc, I already did Esc, but I haven't figured out the click outside the window yet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom hook that will detect the click outside your component.

To achieve it, you have to use useRef in React.

Here's an implementation of the hook:

```
import { RefObject, useEffect } from 'react';

const useClickOutside = (ref: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>, handler: (e: Event) => void) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let isStartedInside = false;
    let isStartedWhenMounted = false;

    const listener = (event: Event) => {
      // Do nothing if `mousedown` or `touchstart` started inside ref element
      if (isStartedInside || !isStartedWhenMounted) return;
      // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target as HTMLElement)) return;

      handler(event);
    };

    const validateEventStart = (event: Event) => {
      isStartedWhenMounted = Boolean(ref.current);
      isStartedInside = Boolean(ref.current && ref.current.contains(event.target as HTMLElement));
      listener(event);
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', validateEventStart);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', validateEventStart);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', validateEventStart);
      document.removeEventListener('touchstart', validateEventStart);
    };
  }, [ref, handler]);
};

export default useClickOutside;
```